# How do I use try in a function?

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner to Python. I am trying to have the user input their age. This is my code:

```
def ageInput():

    try:
        age = int(input("Age: "))
    except:
        print("Please enter a number")
```

If they enter anything besides an integer, it stops them. When I run this code, nothing is printed. When I remove the def ageInput():, it works. I want to run a while loop in this so I have to have the ageInput there. Any help

Comment: You should specify the exact type of error you expect. In this example: ```except ValueError```.

Comment: The problem is not in the `try...except...`. The problem is that you don't call the function. Do `ageInput()` after the function, and see.

Comment: Hello, Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example & this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be, that you forgot to call the function? Your code should look like this.

```py
def ageInput():
    try:
        return int(input("Age: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number")

age = None
while age is None:
    age = ageInput()

# age is now a number
```

Comment: This is still a very poor example of try/except because you should *never* have an `except` without the exception it should process, as @ Péter Leéh commented

Comment: I edit my answer, it has a concrete exception type now.

Comment: If I wanted to make it so that the user input is saved to a nonexisting file, how would I do that?

Comment: Please read the documentation on file IO. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files